# How to form an XML that has data alongside tags

Tags: php, xml

I'm new to PHP. I'm trying to form an XML by concatenating a variable with new tags, data and forming a string. Now I want to send this string with tags along the URL. Below is the XML I want to pass -

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$xml .= "<Student>";
$xml .= "<Name>John</Name>";
$xml .= "<Age>5</Age>";
$xml .= "</Student>";
```

But, when I try to echo this string, I get only `John 5` without the tags. How can I get even the tags alongside the data.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code of the displaying page? You will not see the tags once this is loaded in a webpage. Also, what do you mean "send along the URL?"

Comment: @JelleFerwerda I'm using curl to send this XML tags along the URL

Comment: Are you try to send xml string as a GET or POST parameter? And where you view result of `echo` comand? In browser?

Comment: @Microbe As POST and I'm trying to print it in the same page before doing POST

Comment: I think that browser expect HTML tags and therefore ignore tags from your xml. Try `header('Content-Type: application/xml');` before `echo`. That header say to browser that now all received data he must interpret as xml.

Answer (score 0):

use `htmlentities()` to show the tags:

```
echo htmlentities($xml);
```

otherwise, the tags get interpreted as HTML by the browser.

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/te3t78